# Facebook: obtain album id just created with Photos.createAlbum

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm developing an iPhone app that creates a Photo Album to hold the pictures that the user is going to upload.

On `- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {` I'm trying to obtain the aid returned with this code:

```
else if ([@"Photos.createAlbum" isEqualToString: request.method]) {

        NSLog(@"[Photos.createAlbum:dialogDidSucceed] succeed");

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *aid = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [request.params objectForKey:@"aid"]];

        [prefs setObject:aid forKey:_ALBUMID];
        [prefs synchronize];

        //[prefs release];
        [aid release];

        if (pendingUploadImage) {
            [self btnUploadImage];
        }
    }
```

[Here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.createAlbum#Example_Return_XML) said that the **aid** is returned, but I don't know where.

How can I obtain album id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anywhere, it must be in `result`, which is a dictionary containing the response data from the web service. It certainly cannot be part of the request (where your code assumes it is).

Comment: Obviously. This is very embarrassing.